# Method in QGIS to do a select by radius but ignore "islands"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, select-by-location, qgis-modeler

I am looking for a process in QGIS to run a selection from a given point based of a radius that ignores "islands". For example you may have a body of water which acts as a natural barrier past which I do not want to select any features.

Please see my image as an example:

[image]

As you can see in this example the selection was made from a point on mainland England but polygons on the Isle of Wight has been selected even though they are separated by the Solent.

[image]

It may also be the case that the multi polygon itself does not contain an island but the selection creates one (see above).

I am not necessarily looking for a single tool or plugin because I don't think it exists, but is there anything I can incorporate into the graphical modeler to get around this? I'm thinking of a rule that ignores any polygons that do not touch.

Comment: You could put islands on a separate layer from the mainland data.

Comment: @erik thanks for your comment - my example might not be a good one because by island I mean an island created by the selection and not the island itself. For example islands can be created on data sets that loop around on them self.

Comment: @erik I have edited the question which should hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: So you want all selected features to be connected to each other?

Comment: Yes, essentially ignore any features which are not connected to the radius origin.

Comment: Sounds like a topology-based selection approach might help.